# How to group the values which are in excel to a HashMap

Tags: java, excel, hashmap, apache-poi

i have the following excel:

```
Method Name       Status Code
getLoggedinUserDetails  400
createRequisition   400
excelMDM            400
```

and i am able to print the  values as they are in excel using the following code :

```
package com.poc.excelfun;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class ReadExcelData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("attachment_status.xls"));

            //Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

            //Get first sheet from the workbook
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            //Iterate through each rows from first sheet
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();

                //For each row, iterate through each columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    switch(cell.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                             System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                           System.out.print((int)cell.getNumericCellValue()  + "\t\t");
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                             System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            file.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

i want to put the values excluding title `Method Name       Status Code` and  values only like `Key - > getLoggedinUserDetails  and value -> 400` in Hashmap

how to do this.

Please help me to find this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

String key = null
int value = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // use a default value that will never occur in the sheet

HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

while(cellIterator.hasNext()) 
{
    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

    switch(cell.getCellType()) 
    {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            value = cell.getNumericCellValue(); break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
             key = cell.getStringCellValue(); break;
    }

    if(key != null && value != Integer.MIN_VALUE)
    {
        map.put(key, value);
        key = null;
        value = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
}
```

Not the cleanest solution but should work with the iterator for your data format.

If your Spreadsheet framework allows to look up specific cells via index you can make it easier by replacing the while-loop and kust directly retrieve the values from the cells.

Comment: same what i was looking for, thanks for that and +1, but this solution includes first row which is not required, how to do this?

Comment: Since you know what the key of the first row is you can just simply remove it with `map.remove("Method Name")`. But again: only possible for this data format... Alternatively you can just add a flag that skips the inner while-loop for the first row.