# Read remote Excel file

Tags: java, excel, csv

I have an Excel file that looks like this:

[image]

What I'm trying to do now is supply the DEST_NAME_DISPLAY and retrieve the DEST_ID.

As you might have noticed, this file contains a lot of destination, so I don't want to loop over them all to find a DEST_ID. Is this possible? If it is, how?

Comment: `so I don't want to loop over them all to find a DEST_ID. Is this possible?` Yes. `If it is, how?` By using a database. If this isn't an option, I think looping is the only thing you can do.

Comment: @wero, I corrected it. I was thinking of the excel file extentsion when I posted this question so I confused it with xml. Thanks

Comment: @BackSlash Oke thanks for the answer. Sadly enough a database is not an option because the excem file is on a remote FTP server...

Comment: How would you handle the DEST_NAME_DISPLAY "Andorra"? would it give 19698 or 19699?

Comment: @Burkhard, Thanks for pointing that out to me!

Comment: How often does the file change? If it never changes (or rarely) you could parse it into a database (or a Map<String, Integer>). The retrieval will then be fast.

Comment: @Burkhard, It rarely changes so thanks for answer. do you have some example code on how to create a map from an excel file?

Comment: @GlennVanSchil just [google it](https://www.google.es/search?q=java+excel+to+pam&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=nnkfVoeZJIq_aNSeiVg#q=java+excel+to+map), there are plenty of examples [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458640/how-to-group-the-values-which-are-in-excel-to-a-hashmap) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479882/how-to-store-values-from-excel-to-some-collection-in-java) [3](http://www.developer.com/lang/article.php/10924_3792296_2/Reading-Excel-Files-with-Apache-POI-HSSF.htm) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095135/writing-to-excel-file-using-hash-map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the file rarely changes you can read it into a Map.

For example like this: [How to group the values which are in excel to a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458640/how-to-group-the-values-which-are-in-excel-to-a-hashmap)

Afterwards, you can get the value like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = ... // from file
Integer value = map.get(key);
```

Edit: [BackSlash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1759845/backslash) points out, a database is better because the data will remain after the application quits. Of course it is a little harder to set up, but worth considering if you need persistance.

Comment: I would also add that a database would be better. The hashmap will be deleted from memory as soon as the application quits, so the excel file will have to be re-read each time, unless you serialize the map to a file each time. If the OP uses a db this data will remain after the application quits.

Answer (score 1):

In java8 you can use the functional programming features to get it done.Following is the psuedo code written in javascript.

```
var myColumnDefs = [
    {key:"Tokyo", value:"2211"},
    {key:"Akihabara", value:"2211"},
    {key:"Kyoto",value:"3344"}]
var input = "Kyoto"
var p = myColumnDefs.filter(function(x){ return x.key==input }).map(function(x){return x.value});
alert(p);
```

The following is the longer version which is written in Java 8

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class Location{
    public String areaCode;
    public String areaName;
    public String otherInfo;

    public Location(String areaName,String areaCode,String otherInfo){
        this.areaCode = areaCode;
        this.areaName = areaName;
        this.otherInfo = otherInfo;
    }

}
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Location[] locations = {
        new Location("Tokyo","2211","TK"),
        new Location("Akihabara","2211","AHR"),
        new Location("Kyoto","3344","KT")
    };
    String input = "Tokyo";
    Location[] output =(Location[]) Arrays.stream(locations).filter(x->x.areaName.equals(input)).toArray(size -> new Location[size]);

    System.out.println(output[0].areaCode);


  }
}
```